What is your favorite Durga/Chandi - stotra/kavach/namavali etc?
Personally I recite Durga Saptashloki, Argala, 32 names, Kunjika stotra daily. Sometimes the 108 namavali.
There are so many devi stutis, suktams, kavach etc.
I am interested in learning what are some of your favorite ones?
Doesn't really matter if you read them regularly or not.

32 names of maa is very popular. Unfortunately, there is no proper commentary on it. If you can find please do share.

32 names is in Geeta press Durga Saptasati, in case you are looking for it. They also have purascharan details in it.
